# $\int\limits_0^{1/2} \ln(Γ(x)) \cos⁡(\pi x)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function

Evaluate:
      $$\int\limits_0^{1/2} \ln(Γ(x)) \cos⁡(\pi x)\ dx$$

I tried to find this integral using different methods including integration by parts, without success.Question from Jalil Hajimir

Comment: Why do you believe that this integral has a closed-form result?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: what? $\log\Gamma(x)$ just has a logarithmic (integrable) singularity at the origin and $\cos(\pi x)$ is extremely regular, so the integral exists.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28ln%28gamma%28x%29%29cos%28pix%29%29++from+0+to+1%2F2

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1008732/44121

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio:  You're right... my mistake.  (I used $\Gamma$ not $\ln \Gamma$.) . I'll delete my comment, above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrowing the Malmsten-Kummer Fourier series from [M.N.C.E post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1008732/44121)
$$\color{blue}{\ln{\Gamma(x)}=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)+\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left\{\frac{1}{2n}\cos(2\pi nx)+\frac{\gamma+\ln(2\pi n)}{n\pi}\sin(2\pi nx)\right\}}$$
we get
$$ \int_{0}^{1/2}\cos(\pi x)\log\Gamma(x)\,dx = \frac{\log(2\pi)}{2\pi}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left\{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2\pi n(4n^2-1)}+\frac{\gamma+\ln(2\pi n)}{n\pi}\cdot\frac{2n}{\pi(4n^2-1)}\right\} $$
and the RHS can be simplified into
$$ \frac{\log(2\pi)}{2\pi}+\frac{1-\log(2)}{2\pi}+\frac{2}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\gamma+\log(2\pi)+\log(n)}{(4n^2-1)} $$
then into
$$ \frac{1+\log(\pi)}{2\pi}+\frac{2}{\pi^2}\left[\frac{\gamma+\log(2\pi)}{2}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}\right]$$
which, except for known constants, depends on the derivative of the [Dirichlet $\beta$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) at $s=1$.
Malmsten showed that
$$ \beta'(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}(\gamma-\log\pi)+\pi\log\Gamma\left(\tfrac{3}{4}\right) $$
and this gives a closed form in terms of $\pi,\log\pi,\gamma$ and $\log\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right).$

Comment: The name Malmsten is totally new for me. +1 and happy new year 2020!

Comment: I do not see how that sum can be expressed in terms of $\beta'(1)$. Could you elaborate?